# Inaccurate python tesseract result

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm attempting to use Tesseract to read the text of an image that I have saved.

```
image = cv2.imread(r"TribeLog.png")
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
```

The above code is what I'm using, however, this is yielding inaccurate results as shown:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoAo2.jpg) and [Tesseract Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4dXT.png)

Any help for obtaining a more accurate result would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

- 1. Apply [simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 2. Set page-segmentation-mode to [6](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

Result of the threshold:

[image]

When you read:

```
BLUE - Lvl 245 {Triceratoos)
Day 7449, 15:37:39: OMW2FYB froze Adolescent
Manaaarmr - Lvl 374 iManacarmr) |
Day 7449, 15:26:03: OMW2FYB froze Adolescent F
278 M OMW - Lvl 401 iManaaarmr |
‘Day 7445, 18:03:39: Human froze w22I - Lvl 330
Pteranedon)
iDay 7445, 17:59:16: Human froze w22I - Lvl 325
APteranodon)
Day 7445, 17:55:48: Human froze w22! - Lvl 328
4Preranedont
‘Day 7445, 17:51:59: Human froze w22l - Lvl 326
{Preranedon)
\Day 7445, 17:48:39: Human froze w22I - Lvl 325
{Pteranodon)
\Day 7445, 17:45:02: Human froze w22I - Lvl 327
i{Pteranodoni
!Day 7445, 16:44:30: Human froze Adolescent w22l - |
‘Lvl 214 (Tek Stecasaurus! |
)— Day 7445, 15:10:14: Human froze Adolescent Tek
‘Steaosaurus - Lvl 244 (Tek Steaosaurusl |
{Day 7445, 13:51:48: Human froze Adolescent Snow |
‘Owl - Lvl 275 [Snow Owll :
‘Day 7445, 13:25:42: Human froze Adolescent Snow |
\— ‘Owl - Lvl 289 (Snow Owl} |
iDay 7445, 13:22:14: Human froze Adolescent Snow
‘Owl - Lvl 344 (Snow Owl) !
:Day 7445, 12:52:11: Human froze Adolescent Tek |
‘Steaosaurus - Lvl 211 (Tek Steaosaurus) 1
|Day 7439, 14:54:53: Human froze Adolescent w22I - I
iLvl 242 (Tek Steaosaurus} |
Day 7439, 14:51:13: Human froze Adolescent w22I -
‘Lvl 283 (Tek Steaosaurus} |
Day 7439, 14:47:26: Human froze Adolescent w22l - '
iLvl 316 {Tek Steaosaurus} |
'Day 7439, 14:42:46: Human froze Adolescent w22I - |
iLvl 244 (Tek Stecosaurus) I
‘Day 7438, 23:15:48: Human froze ddd - Lvl 217 |
‘4{Giganotesaurus} j
)— Day 7437, 23:50:36. OMW2FYB froze M OMW PINK - |
iLvl 412. (Manaaarmr) |
‘Day 7437, 23:15:57: OMW2FYB froze Juvenile i
‘Manaaarmr - Lvl 377 (Manaaarmrl ;
Day 7437, 04:19:21: Human froze w22! - Lvl 391 |
)— {Manaaarnr) |
'Day 7436, 15:50:53: OMW2FYB froze Juvenile
iManagarmr - Lvl 377 (Manaaarmrl |
Day 7436, 14:31:08: Human froze [p] healed needs |
saddle - Lvl 337 (Triceratops) 1
(Day 7436, 14:18:37: OMW2FYB froze Juvenile |
\ ce
: Reverse Log Order :
_ ON
```

I did not check the result sentence-by-sentence but you can improve by using different preprocessing methods and page-segmentation-modes.